# Create view using logical statement

Tags: oracle, toad

I am working on Oracle using Toad 10. I want to create a view from 5 different tables. It will include some computations as well(addition of quantities) for the final data in view. How can I create it. Its easy for me to do in .net code, however due to performance reason it was decided to do it using a View or a Package. I am not good at database and I would appreciate any kind of help.

Usually I see views from one or 2 tables joined which I can do.

I will try to give a simple scenario of what I am trying to achieve:

Suppose I have 7 tables.

- Person - Gives personal information
- Apple - Gives count of apple sold
- Orange - Gives count of oranges sold
- Grape - Gives count of grapes sold
- Lemon - Gives count of lemon sold
- Cherry - Gives count of cherry sold
- Others - Gives count of other items sold

I want an ouput of the total number of each items sold by each person.
[image: Required output]

Now, here I dont have a Others column, instead of that each item in Others table should be added to any of the fruit based on a category id column in Others table. For example, other items with category id 1 should be added Apple, items with category id 2 should be added to Orange etc.

How can I want to get the data for person id 1.

Comment: Can there be multiple records in `apple`, `orange` etc per person id, or do these table have the person id as primary key?

Comment: There can be multiple records of the same item for the same month, in the apple/orange tables. For example, in a single month itself, he can have 2 transactions for apple/orange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with l_pers as (select personid 
                from person
                where personid = 1)
,    l_apple as (select sum(quantity) qt
                 from apple 
                 join l_pers on (l_pers.personid = apple.personid))
,    l_orange as (select sum(quantity) qt
                  from orange 
                  join l_pers on (l_pers.personid = orange.personid))
,    o_others as (select sum(decode(category,1,quantity,0)) appleqt     
                  ,      sum(decode(category,2,quantity,0)) orangeqt
                  from others 
                  join l_pers on (l_pers.personid = others.personid))
select l_pers.personid as personid
,      l_apple.qt + o_others.appleqt as apples
,      l_orange.qt + o_others.orangeqt as orange
from l_pers
,    l_apple
,    l_orange
,    o_others;
```

Comment: Great. I can understand that. Now, how can I get it on a monthly basis. Lets say that there are 2 other columns in apple, orange and others table called 'Month' and 'Year'. How can I get a data of all the month in a particular year, say 2013.

Comment: You start be stating all requirements in the question and not piecewise after someone has answered the question.

Comment: I am so sorry about that Rene. I thought about that piece of requirement after seeing the answer. I was wrongly under the assumption that if I can get for one case, I could easily group by month. Do you think I should post another question itself with that?

Comment: You could use the same structure. Add month and year in the data providers and a group by. Tie them all together in the from clause using where.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
select
  id                 person_id,
  sum(apple .amount) apple,
  sum(orange.amount) orange,
  sum(grape .amount) grape,
  sum(lemon .amount) lemon,
  sum(cherry.amount) cherry,
  sum(others.amount) others
from
  person             left join 
  apple   using (id) left join
  orange  using (id) left join
  grape   using (id) left join
  lemon   using (id) left join
  cherry  using (id) left join
  others  using (id)
where
  id = 1
group by id;
```

See also [this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a15e/4)